# got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to do a query when the object has the status = 'Opened'. And display in a table where I will have a button to give a solution for my form and change status='Pending'. But when I click in the button I get this error.

What I'd like to do for really is display was a form for each data, but when I do a for loop for each one form my data insnt show, how you can see **my editable.html**. I just get the buttons to do an action, and they are working fine.

[image: Editale.html]

url:

```
 path('manutencao_os_status/<int:id>', views.manutencao_ordem_de_servico, name='manutencao_os_status'),
    path('manutencao_ordem_de_servico/', views.manutencao_ordem_de_servico, name='manutencao_ordem_de_servico'),
```

views.py

```
def manutencao_ordem_de_servico(request):
    ordem_servico = OrdemServico.objects.filter(status='Aberto').order_by('id')
    form = FormOrdemServico(ordem_servico)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        return render(request, 'ordemservico/manutencao_ordem_de_servico.html', {
            'form': form,
            'ordem_servico': ordem_servico
        })

    form = FormOrdemServico(request.POST, ordem_servico)

    if not form.is_valid():
        return render(request, 'ordemservico/manutencao_ordem_de_servico.html', {
            'form': form,
            'ordem_servico': ordem_servico
        })

    ordem_servico.save()

    return redirect('ordemservico:manutencao_ordem_de_servico')


def manutencao_os_status(request, id):
    ordem_servico = OrdemServico.objects.get(pk=id)
    ordem_servico.status = 'Em Aprovação'

    ordem_servico.save()

    return redirect('ordemservico:manutencao_os_status')
```

html:

```
 {%extends 'base.html' %}
    
    {%block conteudo %}
    <h1>Ordens de Serviço</h1>
    
    <section class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="card card-primary">
                    <div class="table table-bordered">
    
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Condition:</td>
                                <td>ID:</td>
                                <td>Name:</td>
                                <td>Status:</td>
                                <td>Solution:</td>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            {% for os in ordem_servico %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                               <a href="{% url 'ordemservico:manutencao_os_status' os.id %}"
                               class="btn btn-success">Aprovar</a>
                                </td>
                                <td>{{os.id}}</td>
                                <td><a href="{% url 'ordemservico:editar_ordem_de_servico' os.id %}"> {{os.name}}</a></td>
                               
                                <td>{{os.status}}</td>
                                
                                <td>{{os.solution}}</td>
    
                            </tr>
                            {%endfor%}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
        
        
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        
        {% endblock %}
```

my editable.html:

```
{%for os in ordem_servico %}
<form action="{% url 'ordemservico:manutencao_os_status' os.id  %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset>
        <legend><h2>Ordens de Serviço</h2></legend>
        <table class="table">
            {{ os.form }}
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Solucionar</button>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>

    </fieldset>
</form>
{%endfor%}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You routed to the wrong view, it should be:

```
path(
    'manutencao_os_status/<int:id>',
    views.manutencao_os_status,
    name='manutencao_os_status'
),
```

In the view you should likely redirect to the `manutencao_ordem_de_servico` view:

```
def manutencao_os_status(request, id):
    ordem_servico = OrdemServico.objects.filter(pk=id).update(
        status='Em Aprovação'
    )
    return redirect('ordemservico:manutencao_ordem_de_servico')
```

---

> **Note**: A GET request is *not* supposed to have *side-effects*, hence updating
> objects when a user makes a GET request, is not compliant with the HTTP
> standard. Therefore it might be better to update a `OrdemServico` with a POST request.

Comment: thanks bro, could you help me again? How I said before I'd like to show editable fields, but when I try to do a editable.html to this(I edit my question and put the code in) I just get the button.

Comment: In fact, the view that i'm using to filter and show the editable form in the page is the first one **manutencao_ordem_de_servico**. I've seen your edit but still not showing my data in the editable html, just buttons(and it is working how I would like). My view **manutencao_os_status** is just to update `OrdemServico`

Comment: I edited the question and put picture to you se better.

Comment: Can you explain what problem still remains? It is not entirely clear for me.

Comment: the problem is that I would like to have on page editable.html a form editable por each OrdemServico. And this way that I've made the fields aren't shown on the page, just the buttons wich will update the status field. Did you got it?

Comment: @AlexandredasNevesRodrigues: In that case you probably want to work with *formsets*: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets